# Symfony uses wrong entity class in EntityType

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

Symfony version: 4.4.5

I have a form type `QuestionType` which has a `inputType` field - a relation to the entity `inputType` (manyToOne). I've set the `class` parameter of the `EntityType` field type to entity `InputType`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\InputType;
use App\Entity\Question;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class QuestionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('question', TextType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'label'    => 'Frage',
            ])
            ->add('multipleAnswers', CheckboxType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label'    => 'Mehrere Antworten zulassen',
            ])
            ->add('inputType', EntityType::class, [
                'class'         => InputType::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('i')
                        ->orderBy('i.name', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'name',
            ])//->add('answers')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Question::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

By open the form in my browser, I get the following Error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 45 near 'name ASC': Error: Class App\Entity\Answer has no field or association named name
```

I cannot understand why - the `inputType` field of the form is correctly configured...

Comment: I think we need to see the App\Entity\InputType class to be able to help, is it extending the Answer class?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the nameSpace and class name are correct.